# Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g"

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm using Geofire to do a circleQuery in a certain area. With my observers set up I am getting back locations, however, with the location I also get back a "Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g""

My db for my geofire looks like this karmadots/geofire/{events}

```
"rules": {
  "karmadots": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true, 
    "geofire": {
      "$events": {
        ".indexOn": ["g"]
      }
    }   
  }
```

I've also tried:

```
"rules": {
  "karmadots": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "geofire": {
      ".indexOn": ["g"]
    } 
  }
}
```

Both don't make the message go away. Is there something else I can try reading or try as an example?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

My path is xxxxx.firebaseio.com/karmadots/geofire/{keys}

This is how I query:

```
func setupListeners(query: GFQuery){

    // Event is in initial area or entered area
    query.observeEventType(GFEventTypeKeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        println("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'\n")
    })

    // Event left area
    query.observeEventType(GFEventTypeKeyExited, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        println("Key '\(key)' left the search area\n")
    })

    // Event moved but is still in area
    query.observeEventType(GFEventTypeKeyMoved, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        println("Key '\(key)' moved in the search area and is at location '\(location)'\n")
    })

}
```

Comment: The latter looks more likely to be correct. But just to be sure, can you show us the query you run? Preferably showing the entire path from root to the actual events used in the geofire query.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've edited my original post and included the query. Not sure if thats what you meant by my entire path.

Comment: Hmm... when I run a regular Firebase query on it, I get no errors: `new Firebase('https://karmadots.firebaseio.com/karmadots/geofire/').orderByChild('g').startAt("9q8yywcp39").endAt("9q8yywcp39").limitToFirst(3).once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })`. That is essentially what GeoFire does too.

Comment: Does the order by child happen under the karmadots/geofire path? Isnt there one more directory before you can order by g i.e. karmadots/geofire/{keys}/g.
Secondly, is my query adding the orderByChild()? Or is that added by the .indexOn?

Comment: When I removed the brackets from ".indexOn": ["g"] and just used ".indexOn" : "g", it worked.

Comment: OK, perfect. Can you post it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Removing the brackets around ["g"] fixes the problem. Here is the final piece of code:

```
"rules": {
  "karmadots": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "geofire": {
      ".indexOn": "g"
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the only working answer i could find. thanks!

Comment: The log message quoted in the OP has the correct syntax - not sure how the brackets got involved.