# How do I structure my Geofire posts in my firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have noticed on all other posts that any node/key with children was saved in the database in quotes and mine are not.

mine

```
Locations{
    indexOn: "g"
}
```

others/what I assume it should be

```
Locations{
        ".indexOn": "g"
    }
```

I didn't think anything of it till I came up on a similar error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287977/retrieving-location-data-with-radius-using-firebase-geofire) with the  ".indexOn". I tried adding ".indexOn" but i received the error that no key can have the symbol `.`(along with a few other characters that aren't allowed) so I put it in without the `.` like so:

`Locations{
     (specific id){
        g: "345jh3i5jh"
        l{
           0: 37
           1: -120
         }
        indexOn: "g"
        user: "0987435098723098Gjhf90"
    }
}`

So It seems to work as the `observeEventType` is returning the correct result sometimes but it still also gives me the error that i need to put ".indexOn" in database. How do I do this?

---

Any help and explicit examples would be appreciated as there are probably more problems with everything than I addressed. Doing this in swift and thanks for the read!

Comment: Please limit to a single question per post and provide the minimal code that reproduces the problem that the question is about. For your first question I now have trouble understanding what the problem is.

Comment: I have fixed my question to just the second problem as I was able to solve the first one. Thanks for checking it out @FrankvanPuffelen, I see you're becoming the guru on firebase here at stack

Comment: Totally solved my issue!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to add index definitions to your database. That is indeed a great way to ensure the server can order and filter the data *before* returning the results to your app.

Indexes are defined by adding them to your Firebase Database rules in the Firebase Console > Database > Rules. Don't try to add them to your actual database, since:

- you won't be able to save them, since they have a `.` in their key, which is an illegal character in the database
- adding them won't help, since the database server only searches for `.indexOn` definitions in the database rules

See the [Firebase documentation on adding indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for more.